# How do I access the population of a leaf node in my C# Accord.NET decision tree?

Tags: c#, accord.net

I am trying to test whether a case belongs to a specific leaf node of my Accord.NET decision tree. In other words, I want to test each other case for whether or not it belongs to the leaf node in question. The goal is to perform a logistic regression on the leaf population.

To give some background information: In C#, using the Accord.NET machine learning framework, I have a tree,

```
DecisionTree tree
```

Which I have taught to reproduce a set of rules

```
C45Learning treeTeacher = new C45Learning(tree);    
treeTeacher.Learn(inputs, outputs);
```

And now I want to go through each of the inputs,

```
for (int j = 0; j < outputs.Length; j++) {
```

and test whether input *j* belongs to the same leaf as input, say, *0*.

```
  if (leaf(0) == leaf(j))
```

In order to achieve this, I've tried to first make a rule set from my tree,

```
DecisionSet rules = tree.ToRules();
```

and use the method,

```
rules.Equals()
```

but there is no documentation on this particular method, and I have not found any example of usage. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: it would be helpful to show the relevant code you've written so far and explain where you are facing a problem.

Comment: Background information added.